# Send mail from imported account in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I found that it is possible to have several email accounts in Gmail. But how do you send email not from the default Gmail account, but from an imported one?

Comment: [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)

Answer (score 1):

As [the link that @ale provided](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370) indicates, you can send emails through Gmail using an imported account by changing the `From` attribute.  (This article assumes you've already linked your other email address into Gmail; if you haven't, the link above will show you how to do that.)

Here are the instructions from that link for changing the `From` address:

> 1. In the message, click the "From" line.
>      (If you don't see this, click the space next to the recipient's email.)
> 2. Select the address to send from.

If you want to set up Gmail to *always* send from another address, you can see how to do that further down on the same help page, [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370#changefrom).